Anti Frida and JSHook Flutter
Recently my application can be bypassed using JSHook, Frida, and objection. Users can bypass biometrics using fingerprint bypass, so they can successfully log in using biometrics.
Is there a way to block JSHook and block Frida in Flutter?

Frida usually requires a rooted device. If users execute your app on a rooted device they shouldn't be surprised if fingerprint authentication can be bypassed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
